# IP5301 USB Negotiating?

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, diy, electronic-load

Currently trying to get this board to simply supply me 5v through the USB terminals on the back.

https://a.co/d/3mZtA3k

I have the USB + and - hooked to a Wemos D1 Mini V4, and when I activate the KEY button on the charger board (with a battery powering the board), it flashes on for a moment then turns off. I assume this is because the IC (IP5301) needs some sort of indication that there’s a device connected. The Wemos draws about 150mA I believe, so it should be enough for a load-based detection system (so I assume that’s not the issue - I also tried powering four Wemos boards with it, same result). So, I can only assume I have to do something with the D- and D+ pinouts. I tried putting a 160ohm resistor between them, tried just straight shorting them, and nothing works. The datasheet even says that it supports D pin shorting (page 16), so I’m at a loss for why it won’t work.

Datasheet: http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/a7a6128e03ee193cf35e48b28e3df9df.pdf

Hopefully one of you smart fellows can help me out. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.